# Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process() working correctly?

Tags: magento-1, bug

In `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process()` the code...

```
if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
    continue;
}
```

...as far as I can tell should be...

```
if (!$rule->getConditions()->validate($quote)) {
    continue;
}
```

I have come to this conclusion since I am working on a ShoppingCart Rule addition and the `salesrule_validator_process` `dispatchEvent` is not being called when the condition alone is fulfilled, only when both the condition and actions are both fulfilled does the `dispatchEvent` occur.

Do you feel I am correct about the above? I have a feeling I have made an oversight.

Thanks!

Comment: Still remains as "if(!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {" in the latest version of Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Calling validate for an item is correct.
Above that call there is this:

```
if (!$this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
    continue;
}
```

Where `$address` is the shipping address or the biling address if the quote is virtual.
If the rule is not valid for the address you do not reach the validation for the item.

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks for your input but I cannot see the relevance of the address check? Assuming the address check returns true (It always did in my testing) the logic of getActions vs getCondidtions still seems to be backwards.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly...

The Salesrule has two conditions. The conditions under conditions are tested against a quote and the conditions under the actions are tested against items.